# Link to ssh key when using git on windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, putty, ssh-keys

I want to use an ssh key when using git from a Windows machine to a Linux server. I have ssh keys already set-up and can connect via ssh through PuTTy. How do I tell git to use this key to connect via ssh?

I have looked through other posts and couldn't find this exact issue

Thanks
Tom

Comment: You need to convert the putty key to openssh format

Answer (score 0):

Please create in your windows home directory file: `.ssh/config` and put into this:

```
Host <your.git.hostname>
  IdentityFile <path.to.ssh.key.pem>
```

Now you can try from console:

```
ssh -v <your.git.hostname>
```

after this you can see which key file is used

---

Another way is setting GIT_SSH environment variable to point to plink.exe

Comment: i don't seem to have the ssh command, will installing it screw up putty or is it a case of setting environment variables to find the ssh?

Comment: If you install git for windows https://git-for-windows.github.io/ I think, that you have ssh command installed with git bash